# How to i take data form last entry stored in my sql database as output in php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I have made a form in php and the answer entered is stored in mySQL database.
It is stored by incrementing id by 1 in my table
On the next page i take the answers from the stored data and display it.
But this will show me also the answers entered previously.
How can i display only the answers from last id entered?
Also i dont want to delete entries from mysql database

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC` and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: ...ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,  Limit 1 means only last entry

Comment: better store the id as you save the new entry ([insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)) and pass this id to next page.

Answer (score 0):

On the form page:

```
session_start(); // At the top of the page


$last_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($db); // Just after the mysql insert query

// Save the id in session so that it is available on the next page
$_SESSION['last_inserted_id'] = $last_inserted_id;
```

On the other page

```
session_start(); // At the top of the page

if(isset($_SESSION['last_inserted_id'])){

    $the_last_inserted_id = $_SESSION['last_inserted_id'];

    // Query now the database

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i display only the answers from last id entered?

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = "database";

$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);
$sql= SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
$data = $conn->query($sql);

if ($data->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " .$row["id"];
    }
}
```

The "LIMIT 1" means that you only want to get just 1 row from your table and considering ORDER BY DESC it will mean that the last id number you inserted will be selected (because is in descendant order which means that you will get the highest id number)

I hope my example is clear enough.